# How do I enable map contact identifier and contact identifier source by default?

Tags: list-manager

I would like to have the map contact identifiers and map contact identifiers source checkboxes selected by defualt. I thought that this would be located on the item in the core db but I did not see anything. Anyone have an idea of how I can achieve this? I have attached a screenshot of what I am attempting to set by default. This a on Sitecore 9.0.2.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this configuration is not a part of items. I found only one way how to achieve your requirement. So we need to override the following file:

*\sitecore\shell\client\Applications\ListManager\Controls\ImportMapTo\ImportMapTo.js*

Look at the following image:

[image: change a default behavior of checkboxes]

You need to change the values in yellow to "true".

After the clearing a browser cache and page reloading, the checkboxes became checked by default.

I tested on Sitecore 9.3, but I don't think it works in different way on previews versions.

Comment: Thank you. Artsem. I made it to the correct application but was looking at the wrong control js file. I am going to accept your answer but I would like to note a few things. Although setting these to true does all the checkboxes to be prechecked, it does not make the appropriate dropdown fields appear. But that is done within the same file as well. You have to remove the mapToRowPanel.$el.hide(); in lines 127 and 133. You should also remove ManualMap.off() and idenifierSourceMap.off() located above the lines of code you called out in your answer. Thank you again for your help with this issue.